# Announce HTTPS version of web page without redirecting

Tags: http, ssl, redirect, https

My website is available via HTTP and HTTPS. I like to keep the non-ssl HTTP version in case something bad happens and the SSL certificates don't get renewed after 3 months (letsencrypt certificates are only valid for that long).

Is there a way to announce the availability of the HTTPS version when visiting the website via HTTP, but without redirecting or forcing the browser to use HTTPS?

(When forcibly redirecting clients to HTTPS, and the SSL certificate updates stop for whatever reason, the redirect will still be in place, making the website unusable.)

Comment: What about some sort of small overlay (created using JavaScript) may be on the top of the page tells the user something like "This site is also available using HTTPS click here to switch".

Comment: That would not help automated tools to discover the HTTPS variant.

Comment: Automated tools only understand a redirect. If you want to redirect automated tools you should implement a conditional forwarding based on the provided user agent. Known web browser can use HTTP, all the other are redirected to HTTPS.